# Strange error on Angular project and safari with unexpected token

Tags: angular, safari, unexpected-token

Safari browser with version 13.1 show error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=' and that doesn't specify the line number or file.Angular version is 16

Is there any way to narrow down which request or script is causing the error?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to a [nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment).
This old version doesn't support it.

You should change the `browserslist` config to include Safari 13 (which by the way is not officially supported anymore by Angular).

Comment: Thanks,it is work))),sorry for this delay